# Error propagation from P-V error to RMS error

Tags: mathematical-statistics, rms, error-propagation

I have a question about the Error propagation in RMS.

My surface profilometer has P-V error with 100 nm (It follows gaussian distribution).
And I investigate the z-axis positions of the object surface with many points (more than 10000 data points).

Now, I want to caculation the RMS error of the object surface.

RMS = SQRT[SUM{(data-reference)^2}/N]

In here, What is the uncertaintyof the RMS?
How I can caculate the error propagation?